# Sum of four complex roots of unity

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

Let $\epsilon$ be a complex $n$ th root of unity and $i$, $j$, $k$ be positive integers so that $k^2\equiv -1\mod n$. It is relevant to see that if $i\equiv \pm j$ or $i\equiv \pm jk$, then

$\epsilon^i+\epsilon^{-i}+\epsilon^{ik}+\epsilon^{-ik}=\epsilon^j+\epsilon^{-j}+\epsilon^{jk}+\epsilon^{-jk}.$

What can we say about the converse of this statement?